# Understanding `markdirty()` in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am unsure what the [`markdirty()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#markDirty-method) function does in QML. The QT documentation of that function does not seem clear to me.

[image]

My interpretation of this is that it allows us to track changes to a small subset of the canvas, so that any changes to that part redraws everything **only in that part**, using `paint()`

Doing `requestPaint()` on the other hand would be far more inefficient because it would redraw the **whole** canvas.

Is this correct? Some simple example codes  would be quite helpful in understanding the usecase of `markDirty()`

Comment: Please copy and paste text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a widely used term in programming especially GUI. Using that you can mark part of the canvas as in need of updating. So if this part is visible the render engine will fire `paint(rect region)` as soon as possible. In the `onPaint` handler you should repaint only items inside this region. `requestPaint()` does almost the same but for all the visible region.

Check the output in the example below:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("QML Test")


    Canvas {
        property var shapes: [20,20,220,20,20,220,220,220]
        id: canvas
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onPaint: {
            console.log(region);
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
            // draw 4 circles
            for(var i = 0;i < canvas.shapes.length;i +=2) {
                var x = canvas.shapes[i];
                var y = canvas.shapes[i + 1];
                var width = 160;
                var height = 160;
                // check the circle is inside the region
                if(!( (x + width) < region.x  || x > (region.x + region.width) || (y + height) < region.y  || y > (region.y + region.height) ) ) {
                    ctx.ellipse(x, y, width, height);
                }
            }
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        property int step: 0
        interval: 2000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            switch(step++) {
                case 0: canvas.markDirty(Qt.rect(0, 0, 200, 200)); break;
                case 1: canvas.requestPaint(); break;
                case 2: timer.stop(); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So using marking parts of the canvas as "dirty" should potentially improve the performance of canvas rendering, correct? Also can one mark a circular region (or more sophisticated region) as dirty, rather than just a rectangular one as you did here? Anyway, thank you for the nice example! Very informative!

Comment: Yes, performance improvement is a target of all this system. That works in all GUI-oriented systems, in Windows for example that allows you to repaint only overlapped part of a window. As for the region shape I guess you could operate with rectangular one only.